# Why inheritance is a bad practice in message contract design

Tags: masstransit

According to the MassTransit creators, having class-based inheritance is not considered as good practice - https://masstransittemp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/inheritance.html

I honestly can't understand why. Here is my simplified real-life scenario: Imagine I have an insurance microservice which is dealing with policies. I know in advance that all the policy-related events are going to have some mandatory fields like: id, product, etc.

```cs
public class InsurancePolicyEvent
{
    Guid EventId { get; set;} 

    Guid PolicyId { get; set; }

    InsuranceProduct Product { get; set;}
}
```

Why can't I simply leverage inheritance here and do not repeat my self in the inherited events, like this:

```cs
public class PolicyTerminated : InsurancePolicyEvent
{
    ...
}

public class PolicyIssued : InsurancePolicyEvent
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To clarify my position, MassTransit recommends the use of interfaces instead of classes, and is perfectly happy with a base type like you've shown above, particularly when it's to enforce fields as a type of event.

[Interface-based inheritance is OK, don't be afraid, but don't go nuts.](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html#correlation)

And right below that, yes, class-based inheritance is discouraged - mainly because developers often do bad things with it. Now, what you've shown above is fine, I see no issues with it.

*However*, once your `InsuranceProduct` class starts to evolve, and some expectation of base-class virtual method dispatch behavior begins to creep into the model, that's the path to bad times. And it might not be you, it might be a less experienced developer who was taught OO class design and figured, why not right?

So, just be careful out there :)